# Use gnome custom themes appearance in KDE?

Tags: kde, themes, gtk

Is there a way to get the colors of a gnome custom theme to KDE without matching every single setting manually? (Theres tons of different color settings in the KDE color schemes, most of which I even don't know where they are applied ...

I use KDE with compiz to run emerald as windows decorator. 
Because I really like the "Elementary"-theme.

Because my eyes aren't that great I had to tweak the gtk-elementary theme for some additional contrast. I saved it as "elementary-piedro".

Now I want to choose this theme in KDE-Systemsettings/appearance/gtk-applications but it doesnt't show the tweaked version? Where is it saved by the normal "gnome appearance preferences"-utility?

Is there a way to use the tweaked settings for KDE-applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly, you need to use gtk+ as your style in KDE, secondly, you would need to edit the gtkrc for your gnome theme as opposed to the theme (in appearance properties). This is the only way that KDE applications can use your GNOME theme (when running KDE).

The gtkrc file is a configuration document, like css is to html, or like preferences are to an application. The gtkrc for a particular theme is usually found in either `/usr/share/themes/themenamegoeshere/gtkrc` or a similar to location, or `/home/username/.themes/themenamegoeshere/gtkrc`.

For elementary just locate the themes folder and find it's gtkrc. Open this with gedit (double click). If it is stored in /usr/share/themes you will need to run gksu gedit (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> ---> gksu gedit) and then open the theme by dragging and dropping on to the gedit window.

Now, you may be a bit confused, so here are some links that explain editing gtkrc files:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=641071
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1016691
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=377397&highlight=gtkrc
- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GTK%2B_By_Example/Theming
- http://live.gnome.org/GnomeArt/Tutorials/UsefulLinks/
- *sorry for all the links, but knowledge is power :D!*

Follow this to change the colour options of your elementary theme, then apply gtk as your kde style.

Comment: hi Roland! I tried but don't get any result. Please explain a bit more further. I added "gnome-settings-daemon" to KDE "Autostart" within the systemsettings. There's no option to set it to run only in KDE. I don't get any effect anyway.

Comment: thx for answering! Sorry but I didn't change anything to my question, there was a second thread on a similar slightly topic - obviously someone changed that one! (Not me though...)

Comment: my mistake :P in any case my updated answer should help you out better this time :P

Comment: But: About which gtkrc file are you talking about? I couldn't find any file with that name anywhere ...

Comment: ohhh I see you don't have a clue then what I'm referring to, hold tight, I'll add more detail to my answer :)! Sorry about that.

Comment: Hello Roland! First of all: thx for your patience. It took a while to look through all the information ... Actually I have tried most of this editing before. I think my problem is I probalbly messed up somewhere else before - all this editing of the gtkrc doesn't work! With KDE 4.6 obviously the way gnome-apps are themed changed again and I still have the old gnome 2 plain look (sry I don't know the name). the choice of the gtk+ style in the kde-systemsettings seems to have no effect at all though listing all my gtk-styles.

Comment: Shouldn't Kde 4.6 just theme all gnome-apps the same way like the chosen KDE-style? Or does this only work with some styles? How to set this up? I can't find any good documentation on all that ...

Comment: You should ask a new question, KDE 4.6 is a bit of a game changer :)

Comment: thx for telling! you're probably right ... see you there then ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but it is worth a look:
http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2008/01/25/theme-gnome-apps-running-in-kde-40/

Comment: Sry, no. The article is outdated. There's even settings dialogues for these settings within the systemsettings of KDE. As I described above. I want KDE and Gnome to use the SAME look, the same theme ... see above ... thx anyway ...